# Complexity of Restoring Optimality after Adding a Point to an Optimal Tour

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-optimization

Suppose an optimal tour through a set $P=\lbrace p_1, ...,\ p_n\rbrace$ of $n$ points is known and also an optimal tour through $Q:=P\cup p_{n+1}$.

Let $T_{opt}\left(P\right)$ denote the set of edges constituting to the optimal tour through $P$ (and analogous $T_{opt}\left(Q\right)$ for the optimal tour through $Q$),

> **Question:**
>   what is known about the minimal cardinality of $T_{opt}\left(P\right)\cap T_{opt}\left(Q\right)$ as a function of $n$?

I am especially interested in the $2D$ Euclidean case, but will also be happy to learn about results related to other instance domains.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with an NP-hard problem, and so the answer to be expected is that the minimal cardinality in question should be big enough to preclude a polynomial-time procedure which would try replacing a small subset of edges in $T_{opt}(P)$ to build $T_{opt}(Q)$.

Whether anyone has constructed a concrete family of graphs showing that this cardinality is big, is a question best asked in a community like [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).